# how to omit the step of setup.bash every time?

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ROS. I have a question.

When I use ROS, I have to do like this every time I start new window of Terminal.

> $ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

and this step enable me to use  "roscd".

Do I have to do this step every time?
Or does anyone know how to skip this step?
If there is a website about this, please let me know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195474/how-to-omit-the-step-of-setup.bash-every-time?/) by [Izumi Hayashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/20514/izumi-hayashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put this line in your `.bashrc` and it will be executed every time you open a terminal automatically.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As explained by domhege open your `~/.bashrc` and change the following line

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

into:

```
source ~/your_ros_workspace/setup.bash
```

or if you don't have it, just add it.
You don't need to type it anymore

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1